# How can I find all a href links for YouTube and remove them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, youtube

I have a string like this:

```
I like this video: <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o03pXLuPl6A&hd=1">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o03pXLuPl6A&hd=1</a>
```

I want to remove both the text and link related to the YouTube video, with jQuery, so it would look like this:

`I like this video:`

How can I do this? Bear in mind, there might be multiple links in the same string that need to be removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
$('a').each(function(){
   if(this.href.match(/youtube\.com/)) $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Very unlikely situation, but this would fail for `http://www.example.com/youtube`.

Comment: @ComFreek that's true

Comment: change `this` to `$(this)`

Comment: @YairNevet Why? `href` is an official attribute of a HTMLAnchorElement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement

Comment: I am trying to do this, yet it won't work - `$('bodyText a').each(function(){`. `bodyText` is my string variable.

Comment: @JamesAnderson585 That won't work because bodyText is treated as a string (you don't embed the actual variable contents).

Comment: @JamesAnderson585 `bodyText` is not a valid HTML element, perhaps you mean `$('.bodyText')`

Comment: @JamesAnderson585 showing your actual HTML might help us giving you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

This'll remove anchor elements that include the strings "youtube.com" or "youtu.be" as part of their href:

```
$('a').filter(function(){ return /youtube\.com|youtu\.be/.test(this.href); }).remove();
```

...except that it removes them from the document and you said you have that text in a string, so you can build on that plan as follows:

```
var bodyText = 'I like this video: <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o03pXLuPl6A&hd=1">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o03pXLuPl6A&hd=1</a>';

var tmp = $("<div></div>").html(bodyText);
tmp.find('a').filter(function(){ return /youtube\.com|youtu\.be/.test(this.href); })
             .remove();
bodyText = tmp.html();
```

That is, create a jQuery object containing a new div that has your string as its content, *then* apply the filter and remove the anchors, then assign the remaining content back to your string variable.